# Center align title, authors and affiliation on first page

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align, titles, affiliation, author

So I have a Latex document in which I want to center align title, authors, and affiliation on first page.

Right now, it is left aligned by default.

```
\begin{document}
\mainmatter              % start of the contribution
\title*{My Title}
\titlerunning{My Title}
\author{AuthorA \and AuthorB}
\tocauthor{AuthorA, AuthorB}
\institute{Department of ABC,\\XYZ Institute, City, Country\\
Email: \{a, b\}@pqr.ijk.mn.st}
\maketitle              % typeset the title of the contribution
\renewcommand{\abstractname}{Abstract.}
\input{abstract}
\input{intro}
\input{design}
\input{evaluation}
\input{related_work}
\input{conclusion}
\input{acknowledgments}
```

My class file is at https://pastebin.com/wLzFsSc8.

Please let me know.

UPDATE: I have got the title, author, and affiliation center aligned. However, I am now facing an issue. The page numbers have been shifted to the bottom center of each page. Earlier, they were on top left in even pages and top right in odd pages. I want it to remain the same. I am using fancyhdr package.

How do I solve this ?

```
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancypagestyle{plain}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[LE]{Author1 and Author2}
\fancyhead[RO]{Title}
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}

\begin{document}

\afterpage{\cfoot{\thepage}}

\thispagestyle{plain}
\begin{center}
    \Large
    \textbf{Title} \\
    \vspace{0.4cm}
    \small{Author 1 and Author 2} \\
    \vspace{0.4cm}
    Department of ABC,\\XYZ Institute, City, Country\\
    Email: \{a, b\}@pqr.ijk.mn.st}
    \input{abstract}
\end{center}
```

Comment: You can build your own titlepage using the `titlepage` environment (don't use `\maketitle` in it)

Comment: And [welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

Comment: @Skillmon Can you please tell me how to center align ? I am new to latex and I can't figure out.

Answer (score 1):

Minimal approach, change it to your liking. The page break was introduced by the `titlepage` environment. If you don't want this break, you can use a `center`-environment instead and drop the `\centering`.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}% for the abstract

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \mbox{}\vfill
  {\huge My Title}
  \vfill
  {\Large AuthorA and AuthorB}
  \vfill
  Department of ABC,\\
  XYZ Institute, City, Country\\
  Email: \{a, b\}@pqr.ijk.mn.st
  \vfill
\end{center}
\blindtext% abstract
\end{document}
```

Comment: This centers the title, author and affiliation but it pushes the abstract to the next page. What I currently have is abstract on the first page, I want it to remain that way. How do I go make the abstract and other content remain on the first page as earlier ?

Comment: Could you please help ? The abstract and other content on the first page is getting shifted to the next page when I apply your code.

Comment: That depends on the way your abstract is formatted. Please update your question containing everything which is necessary to reproduce your issue BUT nothing more (so without any unrelated package and stuff).